# attr_protected Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, attr-protected

Hello I tried To use `attr_protected` on Rails 4 but I couldn't. 
It's say `attr_protected` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one.

What can I do know ?

```
attr_protected :project_id
```

Answer (score 3):

You really should consider using strong parameters instead. Otherwise, you'll run into a mess later with your mass assignment rules.

But, if you insist, add this to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem "protected_attributes", "~> 1.0.7"
```

And run Bundler:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

Start to use [strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) (recommended) or move back to [protected attributes](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes) as suggested.

Comment: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in RolesController#create


    [at]role = project.roles.new(params[:role])

I'm still taking error

Comment: @MuratKAYA you should spend some time to study the subject. Basically you need to assign params like this: `@role = project.roles.build(role_params)` and define private method `role_params` in a controller with permissible list: `params.require(:role).permit(:role_attribute_1, :role_attribute_2)`. Take a look at example here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters.